# Why am I getting 10V at the opamp output instead of 0v?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design

I have a design that it is based on the [CAMPBELL (MAXREFDES4#): 16-BIT HIGH-ACCURACY 4-20MA INPUT ISOLATED ANALOG FRONT END (AFE)](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/reference-design-center/system-board/5562.html) reference design from Maxim. This is how the original looks like:
[image: Signal Conditioning]

And it uses the following voltage supply:
[image: Power Supply]

As you can see, it has two 5V regulators taking their output from a 12V regulator. Then on the opamp/ADC circuit, the 12V supply is feeding the opamp directly and the two 5V regulators are supplying voltage to the ADC and voltage reference.

The whole idea of this reference design is to have the SPI signals isolated from the main processor in this manner:
[image: Digital Isolation]

Due to budget and space constraints, because I need four of these "channels", I had to modify it from the original and I decided to eliminate the SPI isolation chip since I would require two. I did this because it's a rather expensive component and I don't really need the isolation. Also, because this board is powered by 3.3V and the OpAmp requires 12V, the original circuit also contains a step-up transformer that I'm eliminating as well because I have a 12V power supply on my board.

Additionally, the grounds are joined together by a ferrite, so I just decided to remove the ferrite and have a common ground plane for all the circuit on my PCB.

The final design, *the one is not working correctly*, looks like this:
[image: Final OpAmp-ADC]

The power supply looks like this:
[image]

And the GND plane looks like this:
[image: GND Plane]

You can see there that is just a continuous and uninterrupted GND plane.

**So I essentially have the same circuit than the original, or do I?**

The 12V go directly to the OpAmp, I have the two 5V regulators, one for AVDD and other for DVDD *(I had to add a 12V-to-6.5V regulator in the middle because the 5V regulators get really hot with the 12V directly)*. The only big difference is that on the PCB, instead of having two separate planes for AGND and DGND joined together by a ferrite, I have one GND plane for all the board. But still **essentially the same to me**.

Now the weird thing that I don't understand, is that on my board **when I measure the voltage at the output of the +5V AVDD regulator I get 6.75V!** which doesn't make sense! Also, **when I measure the voltage at the ADC input I get 10.7V!** and I have no idea why. In another test I performed, I removed the AVDD regulator completely, desoldered it from the board, but I still get the same 6.75V on AVDD!!

That doesn't make any sense at all! I measured trying to see if there is a short circuit with another part of the board but the AVDD power rail is completely independent and it doesn't have contact with any other traces or rails. This is an image of how the AVDD rail looks like on the board *(The square at the bottom is the +5V AVDD regulator)*.
[image: AVDD Rail]

The voltage on the AVDD rail only went to 0V when I also removed the 12V supply of all the OpAmps which I also don't understand.

Here is a closer look of one of the channels that include the OpAmp, the ADC, the voltage reference, and the passives.
[image: Closer Look]

To remove the OpAmps 12v supply I cut the traces that go to the pin 5 of U8. It is also when I remove the 12V from the OpAmps that the output of the AVDD regulator goes to 5V as it should be.

So, what is going on??? The circuit looks good to me, I don't understand what is happening.

If someone is willing to help I could share the Altium Designer files, I just need to know desperately what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

Your op-amp is driving the +5V rail out of spec through the protection diodes in the ADC. Not a great design, but it should not normally happen.

However, many 4-20mA inputs use 22mA or more to indicate a broken sensor etc. so it's not uncommon that the op-amp might produce more than +5V. Usually a good designer would provide a clamp to keep it from causing problems, particularly when you are sharing supply rails with other channels.

The op-amp output should not be at +10V unless your jumper P3 is missing. It should be at about 0V with no input.

As a quick fix, assuming it's just the jumper missing that is causing the op-amp to rail, I would be tempted to reduce the sense resistor to perhaps 150 ohms and give up a bit of resolution.

Comment: The jumper can be opened or closed. It is opened to be able to sense from 0 to 5 VDC and closed if you want to measure 4-20ma. If I put the jumper the OpAmp output goes to 0.004V which is acceptable, but the problem is when it is opened.

Comment: Shunt P3 with something reasonable like 100K or even 10K. It's completely normal for a voltage input on an instrument to load the input a bit.

Comment: ok, I get what you are saying. But why is this necessary? On the original design, I just have 0V at the OpAmp output without a shunt.

Comment: 1. Because the original design is pretty much sh*t

2. Because the op-amp has a bias current that is generally negative (flows out of the op-amp non-inverting input) below +50°C junction temperature. Generally. That will typically cause it to rail on the positive supply if there is no path for the bias current. Heat it up and it typically won't. Sometimes works, sometimes not.

Comment: P.S. it's quite bad practice to bring a "bare" op-amp output like that to the outside world. Perhaps more  so in your case with no isolation. Think what happens if someone applies -5V to the input. Dead op-amp and surly user.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Could you recommend some resource I can read where I can learn how to properly bringing in outside world signals to OpAmps? Because I haven't been able to find a "real world" OpAmp design book or website. All they contain is textbook circuits not very suitable for real-world applications.

Comment: Probably Jim Williams books will cover this.

Comment: After adding the 10k resistor on P3 I still get 0.004V on all channels when opened, nevertheless, if I add a voltage to any input I get the exact value on the opamp ouput. Do you know why am I seeing 0.004V when the opamp input is opened?

Comment: Not without looking at the datasheets in detail, but generally it’s unreasonable to expect the op-amp output to swing exactly to the negative supply, especially if it has to sink any current at all.  A small load (eg 10K) from op-amp output to ground may or may not help. The better and more expensive/complex way is to give the op-amp a small negative supply rail (eg. -0.25V) that is too small to bother the ADC so no clamp required.